GitLab npm package registy not downloading build files
Have been trying to create a private NPM package in GitLab package registry. But when installing the package I only get a few root files. The build files are not returned even when they are present in the generated zip file of the tag/ release. I hope someone can tell my why I'm only getting the readme.md and package.json files when installing the package.
The .gitignore file below. There is no .npmignore file.
node_modules/
.idea/
.vs/
.vscode/
dist/
*.zip
*.tgz

The package.json:
{
    "name": "javascript-helpers",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "files": [
        "/dist"
    ],
    "main": "dist/javascript-helpers.umd.cjs",
    "module": "dist/javascript-helpers.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/javascript-helpers.js",
            "require": "./dist/javascript-helpers.umd.cjs"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "vite": "^5.3.2"
    }
}

vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
            name: 'JavaScript Helpers',
            fileName: 'javascript-helpers',
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            src: resolve('src/')
        }
    },
})

.gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  image: node:latest
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    policy: push
    paths:
      - node_modules
  script:
    - echo "unsafe-perm = true" >> .npmrc
    - echo "@cadix:registry=https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/" > .npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - npm publish

Partial CI/CD output:
$ npm install
added 57 packages, and audited 58 packages in 2s
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm run build
> javascript-helpers@1.0.0 build
> vite build
vite v5.3.2 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 127 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
dist/javascript-helpers.js  201.63 kB │ gzip: 59.36 kB
dist/javascript-helpers.umd.cjs  146.44 kB │ gzip: 51.13 kB
✓ built in 1.38s
$ npm publish
npm notice
npm notice package: javascript-helpers@1.0.0
npm notice Tarball Contents
npm notice 844B README.md
npm notice 201.6kB dist/javascript-helpers.js
npm notice 146.4kB dist/javascript-helpers.umd.cjs
npm notice 1.1kB package.json
npm notice version: 1.0.0
npm notice filename: javascript-helpers-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size: 111.3 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 350.0 kB
npm notice total files: 4
npm notice
npm notice Publishing to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects//packages/npm/ with tag latest and default access
+ javascript-helpers@1.0.0
Saving cache for successful job
00:03
Creating cache v1.0.0-non_protected...
node_modules: found 1029 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project//v1.0.0-non_protected 
Created cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:03
Uploading artifacts...
dist: found 3 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: Upload request redirected                  location=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs//artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive new-url=https://gitlab.com
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=request redirected
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id= responseStatus=201 Created token=
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded

file structure:

vite.config.js
package.json
dist/
src/

main.js



